# Bad practice to use MySQL and RedShift together?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

A current project I am working on has been exclusively using MySQL as our RDMS. We are currently looking to segment the database into two different databases. One will be moving to RedShift (which runs using a modified Postgresql) while the other will continue using MySQL.

My concern does not stem from splitting the data, but rather how applications will interact with the segmented data. Effectively our current application will be reading static data from RedShift and writing to the MySQL database and I am curious if it is a bad practice to intermingle these Query Languages.

Would it be better to migrate the MySQL DB to Postgres to limit complications arising from their differences?

Comment: You are likely to run into greater complications migrating your data and operational procedures you have. There's no reason to couple the adoption of one additional technology (Redshift) which can be disruptive enough, with a wholesale Db migration. Do one thing at a time and worry about actual rather than hypothetical problems. You can always migrate away from MySQL later if need be.

Comment: That makes sense and helped me mentally sort out some concerns I had. It seems like the real issue with our migration is how we are segmenting our data, and we'll need to ensure that how that line is drawn ensures limited need to jump back and forth between the two DB's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (Looker) work with many customers (100s) that have both MySQL and Redshift.  The progression as their needs grow is usually:

MySQL

MySQL + MySQL slave

MySQL + MySQL **Writable Slave**

MySQL + MySQL **Writable Slave** + Redshift

So your best bet, if you haven't done so is to setup a MySQL Replica slave database.  The replica slave follows your master write database and is essentially an exact copy of your master.

You can also make your Replica **Writable**.  This becomes really useful for building summary tables.   Here are some instructions on how to make a writable replica in RDS, but you can do it with in other systems too.

http://www.looker.com/docs/setup-and-management/database-config/mysql-rds

If have big event data that you want to integrate with your transactional data, the next step is to setup a process that **migrates all your MySQL data** into Redshift and pumps in data from other sources (like your event data, for example).  Moving all the data, gives you the ability to ask any question from Redshift.

Redshift will lag hours or more behind the MySQL database.  If you need to answer real time questions, query MySQL.  If you want general insights, query the Redshift database.

Comment: This is a very nice progression. If we were working on a production environment this would definitely be worth investigating, but for our experimental purposes it is probably overkill.

You certainly get my upvote.